# How do I map property with of type 'Dictionary' with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary, orm, entity

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NameSpaceName
{
    public class WordContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<VmWord> Words { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VmWordLocalization> WordLocalization { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=NameSpaceName.db");
        }
    }
}

namespace NameSpaceName
{
    public class VmWord
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, VmWordLocalization> Localization { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace NameSpaceName
{
    public class VmWordLocalization
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string En { get; set; }
        public string Pl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have VmWord table and I need to add VmWordLocalization as dictionary to be able to get localization variable value by key;

When I try to execute:

> dotnet ef migrations add Add_Localization_Table --context WordContext

I get:

> The property 'VmWord.Localization' could not be mapped, because it is
>   of type 'Dictionary' which is not a
>   supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map
>   this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by
>   using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

How do I map property with of type 'Dictionary'?

Comment: Please explain how do you expect Entity Framework to lay out a Dictionary (a key-value collection) in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you want an object with a `Dictionary` property, is because you want a fast lookup: `Give me the VmWord with the Localization with this Key`. In other words: given a key, you want a fast lookup to the VnWordLocalization object containing this key.

In Entity Framework a `DbSet<...>` represents a table in a relational database. Relational databases don't know the concept of `Dictionary`.

Luckily, a database knows the concept of fast-lookup using a key. Usually this is the primary key, but you can add other indexes that can be used as key.

Alas you forgot to tell us which string you want to use as fast lookup for your `VmWordLocalizations`. Is it `En`? or `Pl`? or is it a completely new key?

If it is a completely new Key, then apparently every `VmWordLocalication` has a property, let's name it `Key`, that is unique in combination with the foreign key `VmWordId`. If it is either `En` or `Pl`, use that as the Key.

```
class VmWord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // every VmWord has zero or more Localizations (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<VmWordLocalization> VmWordLocalizations { get; set; }

    ... // other properties
}

class VmWordLocalization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // every VmWordLocalization belongs to exactly one VmWord using foreign key
    public int VmWordId {get; set;}
    public virtual VmWord VmWord {get; set;}

    // every VmWordLocalization has a property Key, which is unique in combination
    // with VmWordId
    public string Key {get; set;}
}
```

Note: if Key is overall unique, consider using it as a primary Key.

Note 2: in entity framework the non-virtual properties represent the columns in your tables, the relations between the tables are represented by the virtual properties

Note 3: Consider sticking to the [entity framework code-first conventions.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) It eliminates the need of attributes or fluent API. Only deviate from these conventions if you have good reasons. Having to type less characters is not a good reason.

If `Key` can't be your primary key, you'll have to add an extra fast-lookup: an index. This is done in `DbContext.OnModelCreating`

```
protected overrid void OnModelCreating(...)
{
     // Every VmWordLocalization has a property Key, which is unique per VmWordId
     // create an index with (VmWordId, Key) as index key
     var vmWordLocalizationEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<VmWordLocalization>();

     // first index annotation: VmWordId:
     vmWordLocalizationEntity.Property(entity => entity.VmWordId)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnAnnotatin(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
              new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("index_VmWordId", 0)));

     // 2nd index annotation: Key:
     vmWordLocalizationEntity.Property(entity => entity.Key)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnAnnotatin(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
              new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("index_Key", 1)));
}
```

The identifiers `index_VmWord` and `index_Key`, can be anything. They are only identifiers to name the columns of the index.

The numbers 0 and 1 give the order in which the index is sorted: first by`index_VmWordId` then by `index_Key`.

Now if you have a `VmWord` with `Id` == 10, it is possible to add a `VmWordLocation` with a `VmWordId` == 10 and `Key` == "Hello". But if you try to add a second `VmWordLocation` with these values You'll get an exception, just like you would have gotten if you'd added two object with the same key to a dictionary.

Now to get the requested `VmWords` with its localizations in a Dictionary:

```
var vmWordsWithLocalizations = myDbContext.VmWords.Select(vmWord => new
{
      // select only the properties you plan to use:
      Id = vmWord.Id,
      Name = vmWord.Name,

      Localizations.VmWord.VmwordLocalizations
          .Where(vmWordLocalization => ...) // only if you do't want all vmWordLocalizations
          .ToDictionary(vmWordLocalization => vmWordLocalization.Key,  // Dictionary Key
              new                                                      // Dictionary value
              {   // again: select only the properties you plan to use
                  Id = vmWordLocalization.Id,
                  En = vmWordLocalization.Em,
                  Pl = vmWordLocalization.Pl,

                  // no need: you know it equals vmWord.Id
                  // VmWordId = vmWordLocalization.VmWordId

              }),

});
```

If you'll have to do this often, consider creating an extension function:

```
IEnumerable<VmWordWithDictionary> ToVmWordWithDictionary(this IQueryable<VmWord> vmWords)
{
     return vmWords.Select(vmWord => new VmWordEx()
     {
         Id = vmWord.Id,
         Name = vmWord.Name,
         Localizations = vmWord.VmWordLocalizatons
             .Where(vmWordLocalization => ...)
             .ToDictionary(
                 vmWordLocalization => vmWordLocalization.Key        // Key
                 vmWordLocalization => new VmWordLocalizationEx()    // Value
                 {
                      Id = vmWordLocalization.Id,
                      En = vmWordLocalization.Em,
                      Pl = vmWordLocalization.Pl,
                 }),
});
```

Note: For efficiency reasons I don't want to transport more data then needed, so I created two extra classes, containing only the data I need.

Note: because of the Dictionary the return has to be an IEnumerable. You can't do IQueryable LINQ statements after this anymore

Comment: Thank you for answer. I thought about getting values exactly by keys En, Pl, somehow like `lang = "en"` `word.Localization[lang];` because the problem of my project is thet there are too many constant-like calls "en", "pl", and fields like word.localization_en, word.localization_pl used. Adding new localization becames difficulty

Answer (score 0):

It's ont possible to have `Dictionary` property in EF. The solution is to replace `Dictionary` with `ICollection`:

```
namespace NameSpaceName
{
    public class VmWord
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<VmWordLocalization> Localizations { get; set; }
    }

    public class VmWordLocalization
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Key { get; set; }  // key from your previous dictionary

        public string En { get; set; }

        public string Pl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `virtual` in the one-to-many. In entity framework the table columns are represented by non-virtual properties, the relations between the tables are represented by virtual properties

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what is the dictionary and how do you see this mapping to a physical database table (are you looking to have a table with a list of words and then another table with the list of words repeated for each translation)?  I'm 'spit balling' here as I am not sure what it is you are trying to achieve but rather than having a base word with a link of translations you may wish to just have a table which has a word id and a language id which makes up a composite primary key, then you would just apply a where wordid = x and language = y to get the correct version of the word.  Alternatively if you are set on your structure then you would need to implement a child table with a foreign key and define it something like this on the VmWord class:

```
public List<VmWordLocalisation> {get;set;}
```

And then on the child table you would define the foreign key like so

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public VmWord Parent {get;set;}
```

You will also need to set up a composite primary key on the child table to identify the Id and the language

Hope this helps!